# Using a Cateye Strada Smart and Strava

Tags: bike-computer, strava

I wonder has anyone had any experience using the Cateye Strada Smart in Mirror mode and uploading the ride directly to Strava.

I am having problems with the data on Strava being different than on the Cateye Atlas site and am wondering if anyone has solved this problem already?

Thanks in advance.... :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rule of on-line bike ride tracking... every single one has secret-sauce that they use to tweak your ride data.

Strava ignores height information and simply plots your path's point locations on top of a map and that's how high you were.  This method is pretty flawed if your GPS has placed you 20 metres off the road and you're in a deep cutting or on the side of a mountain with a hundred metre vertical drop to that side.

I don't know anything about the Cateye services.

The only answer is to take their results with a big pinch of salt, and merely work on improving the difference between the rides.  Don't compare rides between different providers.

Comment: It gets worse than that.  Sometimes you can't even round trip data in the same system.  I record my rides with Endomondo, but then I export as a GPX to share with my wife and kids.  Once it gets put back into Endo, it match with the original.  Mostly the mileage recorded is off.

Comment: @BPugh If you can use a TCX file, its 5x bigger for the same trip.  I've noticed exporting a GPX file and importing to a new account will mean the second account has a slightly better time than the original.    Try TCX if you can.